# Apache RewriteRule doesn't works as expected

Tags: regex, apache, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have a PHP page (index.php) on an URI like follow:

```
http://example.com/my-folder/
```

the php page need a parameter `?location=name`

```
http://example.com/my-folder/?location=new-york
or
http://example.com/my-folder?location=dallas
```

i create a rewrite rules on .htacces like this

```
<ifModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /

  RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
  RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R=301,L]

  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  RewriteRule ^(.*?)\/my-folder\/?(.*?)$ my-folder/$2?location=$1 [L]

</IfModule>
```

the result expected is

use a URL like this:

```
http://example.com/new-york/my-folder/
```

that redirect to:

```
http://example.com/my-folder?location=new-york
```

it seems works but I have an issue without trailing slash

**The url without trailing slash load the index but failed to load CSS and JS.**

The code:

```
<script src="js/async.js?v=f373bdf3dc0" async></script>
```

try to load the resource:

`https://example.com/new-york/js/async.js?v=f373bdf3dc0`

instead of the expected URL

`https://example.com/my-folder/js/async.js?v=f373bdf3dc0`

Answer (score 0):

Have your .htaccess as this:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
RewriteRule ^ https://%{SERVER_NAME}%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/((?:.*/)?my-folder(?:/.*)?)$ $2?location=$1 [L,QSA,NC]
```

Then  add this just below `<head>` section of your page's HTML: `<base href="/" />` so that every **relative URL** is resolved from that base URL and not from the current page's URL.

Comment: This solution works fine, but I have also another need.
The same page is deployed also under folder:
`/staging/my-folder/`
So with this solution I have to change the base value for publish in staging or not.
If is possible to solve this issue without write different html code for staging/production I would prefere it.

Comment: What is full URL for `/staging/my-folder/` ?